# UIScrollView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a `UIScrollView` with another `UIScrollView` inside. They both are scrolled horizontally and have `pagingEnabled = YES`.
Assume that I started to scroll inner scroll view and reached the most right bound. And if I proceed scrolling in it, then the outer scrollView begins to move. I need to avoid this. Inner view should jump with rubber-band effect, outer should stay at it's place.

Hope it's clear, but here is a sketch:
[image]

I've tried to set `outerView.scrollEnabled = NO;` like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    outerView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

, and it works exactly how I need, if to scroll just in innerView. OuterView is not scrolled anymore. But I have to set `scrollEnabled` back to YES somewhere for the case if I'd want to scroll outerView again.
I've tried to do it here:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    outerView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

, but than I'm getting the same problem: after reaching the the most right bound of innerView outerView scrolls instead of innerView jumps with rubber-band effect.

Any suggestions how to solve a problem?

Comment: in your scrollview delegate methods it doesn't look like your checking which scrollviewViewBeginDragging and which scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. I don't fully understand your needs but this sticks out as wrong.

Comment: try setting a tag on each scrollview then check `if(scrollview.tag == 1) `

Comment: @mkral: I have different delegates for these too views, so I don't need to check a parameter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This solution works always:

```
@implementation InnerScrollViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer*   swipeGesture = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)] autorelease];
    swipeGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    _outerScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    return YES;
}

- (void)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{

}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    _outerScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
        _outerScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    _outerScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

@end
```

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

OLD ANSWER: doesn't work always

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
@implementation InnerView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return NO;
}
```

As I understand, `self.delaysContentTouches = NO;` makes all events to be delivered immediately, and `- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view` prevents passing of these events by responder chain.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried your solution, but doing so blocks the InnerView's subview from any touch events. I have a few buttons inside the inner scrollview as subviews. The scrolling works fine but the buttons are not tappable anymore. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @AlexeyGolikov: Yes, this solution is really tricky, and I'm not sure that it works for every case. I think, WWDC 2013 Session "Exploring Scroll Views on iOS 7" (developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=217) would help, namely the Demo, that starts at 11:00. Unfortunately, I saw this video much later then I asked this question and didn't try to implement it.

Comment: Thank you, @anastasia. Unfortunately the video didn't help me. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: One problem I think with this solution is it breaks good design because the child view has a reference to it's parent. May be OK in simple architectures, but in more complex ones, not so good.

Comment: @DavidJames Of course, it's not necessarily have a reference to parent view, you can send appropriate notification and handle it, as an option. The idea was to show the simplest working example.

Comment: Good example, but if innerScrollView doesn't have big contentSize to scroll it, _outerScrollView will never get scrollEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 2):

Modify your methods by below way:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == innerView)
        outerView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    else
        outerView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == innerView)
    {
         if(innerView.contentOffset.x + innerView.frame.size.width == innerView.contentSize.width)
         {
              outerView.scrollEnabled = NO;
         }
         else
         {
              outerView.scrollEnabled = YES;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but problem is if scrollView has scrollEnabled == NO; than - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView does not called for it anymore. So I can't set scrollEnabled back to YES in this method.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue. I found the solution, but it works only with `innerScrollView.bounces = NO`.

```
@interface PageCtrl ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *innerScrollView;
    @property(nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panLockScroll;
@end

@implementation PageCtrl
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    self.innerScrollView.delegate = self;   

    self.innerScrollView.bounces = NO;   // disable bounces!

    self.panLockScroll = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:nil];
    self.panLockScroll.delegate = self;
    [self.innerScrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.panLockScroll];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer{
    if( gestureRecognizer == self.panLockScroll && 
        otherGestureRecognizer == self.innerScrollView.panGestureRecognizer ){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  outerScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3
                                     target:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ outerScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES; }]
                                   selector:@selector(main)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
```

Remember to adopt the UIScrollViewDelegate in your class declaration and to set the delegate of the innerScrollView to self (do NOT assign the delegate of the outerScrollView)