# UIScrollView as subview of another UIScrollView - scroll the inner one but the outer one also scrolls

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have created two UIScrollViews, one is subview of another. Let's call them inner one and outer one. The question is that when I scroll the inner one, the ouer one is also scrolling. Is there a method that when I scroll the inner one, the outer one disables scroll.

[image]

Comment: I think if you do not config the scrollviews , when you scroll the internal one ,the outer one won't scroll until the internal one can't scroll more(to its edge).

Comment: Probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437515/

Comment: The image I provide for the question explain the problem. Actually I am scrolling the inner scrollView, but the outer scrollView scrolls. I do not config both of them.

Comment: @YuchenZhong:thx for the link, I solve the problem.